# How to translate CURL command to Delphi

Tags: rest, delphi, curl, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm trying to use Delphi 10.2 TREST components with AWS. I have a CURL command that works:

```
curl -X POST --data @GetIDData.json -H "X-Amz-Target: AWSCognitoIdentityService.GetId" -H "Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1" https://cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
```

GetIDData.json contains this:

```
{"IdentityPoolId":"us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}
```

Successful result is this:

```
{"IdentityId":"us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}
```

I'd like to duplicate that result using Delphi TREST components:

```
    ...
    fClient := TRESTClient.Create('https://cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/');
    fClient.SetHTTPHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-amz-json-1.1');
    fClient.SetHTTPHeader('X-Amz-Target', 'AWSCognitoIdentityService.GetId');
    fRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
    fRequest.Client := fClient;
    fRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
//    fRequest.AddBody('{"IdentityPoolId":"us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}', ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
    lJObj := TJSONObject.Create;
    lJObj.AddPair('IdentityPoolId', 'us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
    fRequest.AddBody(lJObj);
    fRequest.Execute;
    str := fRequest.Response.Content;
    ...
```

But the result is an error:

```
{"Output":"__type":"com.amazon.coral.service#UnknownOperationException","message":null},"Version":"1.0"}
```

Downloading OpenSSL and putting the dlls into System32 did not help.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
...
    lClient := TRESTClient.Create('https://cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/');
    lRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
    lRequest.Client := lClient;
    lRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;

    lParam := lRequest.Params.AddItem;
    lParam.name := 'X-Amz-Target';
    lParam.Value := 'AWSCognitoIdentityService.GetId';
    lParam.ContentType := ctNone;
    lParam.Kind := pkHTTPHEADER;

    lParam := lRequest.Params.AddItem;
    lParam.name := 'Content-Type';
    lParam.Value := 'application/x-amz-json-1.1';
    lParam.ContentType := ctNone;
    lParam.Kind := pkHTTPHEADER;
    lParam.Options := [poDoNotEncode];

    lRequest.AddBody('{"IdentityPoolId":"us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}', ctAPPLICATION_JSON);

    lRequest.Execute;
...
```

WireShark was not as helpful as I wanted because its doc is out of date and I'm using encryption. But the website mentioned by @Christophe Morio in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/291424/how-do-you-display-post-data-with-curl) post made finding a solution a piece of cake.